# edit date mask in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using ui mask for writing Date .
the problem is i want to write year at first .

here is my demo : http://jsfiddle.net/XS4R6/85/

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text"
        ng-model="date"
        ui-mask="99/99/9999"
        />  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XS4R6/86/)

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text"
        ng-model="date"
        ui-mask="9999/99/99"
        />  
</div>
```